# How to transpose columns to Rows using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I transpose an array from columns to rows using Angular framework?

From:

```
 [
{Knowledge: "2",Performance: "1",Skill: "1.5",Understanding: "2",name: "Allan"},
{Knowledge: "2",Performance: "1",Skill: "1.5",Understanding: "2",name: "Melanie"},
{Knowledge: "2",Performance: "1",Skill: "1.5",Understanding: "2",name: "Angelo"},
{Knowledge: "2",Performance: "1",Skill: "1.5",Understanding: "2",name: "Matthew"}
]
```

To:

```
[
{name: "Allan", component: "Knowledge", score: "2"},
{name: "Allan", component: "Performance", score: "1"},
{name: "Allan", component: "Skill", score: "1.5"},
{name: "Allan", component: "Understanding", score: "2"},
{name: "Melanie", component: "Knowledge", score: "2"},
{name: "Melanie", component: "Performance", score: "1"},
{name: "Melanie", component: "Skill", score: "1.5"},
{name: "Melanie", component: "Understanding", score: "2"},
{name: "Angelo", component: "Knowledge", score: "2"},
{name: "Angelo", component: "Performance", score: "1"},
{name: "Angelo", component: "Skill", score: "1.5"},
{name: "Angelo", component: "Understanding", score: "2"},
{name: "Matthew", component: "Knowledge", score: "2"},
{name: "Matthew", component: "Performance", score: "1"},
{name: "Matthew", component: "Skill", score: "1.5"},
{name: "Matthew", component: "Understanding", score: "2"}
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woth with `Array.reduce()` to transform the array by iterating each property in the object, adding it as an object into array.

```
let inputs: {
  Knowledge: string;
  Performance: string;
  Skill: string;
  Understanding: string;
  name: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}[] = [{ Knowledge: "2", Performance: "1", Skill: "1.5", Understanding: "2", name: "Allan" }, { Knowledge: "2", Performance: "1", Skill: "1.5", Understanding: "2", name: "Melanie" }, { Knowledge: "2", Performance: "1", Skill: "1.5", Understanding: "2", name: "Angelo" }, { Knowledge: "2", Performance: "1", Skill: "1.5", Understanding: "2", name: "Matthew" }];

let results = inputs.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let obj: { [key: string]: string } = { name: cur.name };
  
  for (let prop in cur) {
    if (prop === "name")
      continue;

    obj = { ...obj, component: prop, score: cur[prop] };
    acc.push(obj);
  }

  return acc;
}, [] as { [key: string]: string }[]);
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAlgdgDgVzAZwFwQN4CgIQNIwD2A7qACYDmI6yYATrBQNw4QAKIdAZoXQLYBDGAGNqEWgxjNWAZQDWUYMBr1GLXAFUYZTrSFlGKydNwwBfMRLWsA2nJABPI4wC6zqSwC+NlxAC8EDYY+ESkIJRiAEQATJEANOycPPxCouiRAIzxEPKKyhCZAHQArNlaOnR62oYFsQlmFukAgkpCkRCeCcEEJORU6XWJ3LyCIlFZCblK6RklZdq6YPo1MdkNUQCyIMBCUCDtnZghveH9tdkcwyljM9lT+UWlCeWLy1IDa+ZRTVLbhAddY5hCIfBKXZKjNIFCY5BTTaFzZ4LSpLarvc71L7pDYCMBgAAWIGIBxcLCwoEgdBAyAQwBQ-mg8CQyEKVLICFEAApOQJhMIEsIEHQAJT+AB8mFYFIghAARgArdDBOyOdwUNziVRSDoM4LrdCCuiFdYddQQVjJCCc6VwOiEOCMiCG0XYXC4KBcK22+3+PwBSLrSLC1hup2EGBgWAIEBk0Ny+W6iCFZPxgWEPhwcMgCPob1wBLIYS8MSGmx53yeM24XnCQqIZD4znx4VmzxYVhUsBCmAQGteBI+XvII4qpya4waqza7wuFvtoswZCEUCFYCECicqk0unIFtAA)